# SageMaker API's AsyncPredictor arguments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

The AsyncPredictor class from the SageMaker Inference API has a method called predict_async.

The predict_async method takes an argument described in the docs [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/predictor_async.html#sagemaker.predictor_async.AsyncPredictor.predict_async) as follows:

```
inference_id (str) – If you provide a value,
it is added to the captured data when you enable data capture on the endpoint (Default: None).
```

I want to know what does this argument do and i can't find any examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable data capture SageMaker will append the inference ID:

Assuming your output is JSON the data capture will append the ID for example something like:

```
{"output": 0, "SageMakerInferenceId": "1f1d57b1-2e6f-488c-8c30-db4e6d757861", "SageMakerInferenceTime": "2022-08-30T00:49:15Z"}
{"output": 1, "SageMakerInferenceId": "22445434-0c67-45e9-bb4d-bd1bf26561e6", "SageMakerInferenceTime": "2022-08-30T00:49:15Z"}
```